# Bluetooth Vodafone TV remote not connecting to Linux /w bluez

Tags: linux, bluetooth

Im running a mostly fresh install of Arch Linux(5.19.12) with bluez(5.65).  The specific bluetooth device in question is the [Vodafone TV Remote](https://www.red-dot.org/index.php?f=14752&token=be97ffe9ada11ba28de709461a2e16a7fdcb409e&eID=tx_solr_image&size=large&usage=hero)

`bluetoothctl info`

```
Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 (public)
        Name: VODAFONE REMOTE CONTROL
        Alias: VODAFONE REMOTE CONTROL
        Appearance: 0x0180
        Paired: no
        Bonded: no
        Trusted: no
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        ManufacturerData Key: 0x0093
        ManufacturerData Value:
  02 85 0f 00 57 41 4b 45 55 50 e0 00              ....WAKEUP..
...
```

The typical pair attempt goes like this.  Although I have tried many variants without any success.  Sometimes Im able to get it to connect my some magical chance, but are unable to replicate.

```
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 34:20:03:DF:2E:6A Powered: yes
[CHG] Device DF:6C:AD:D9:82:7A Connected: yes
[CHG] Device DF:6C:AD:D9:82:7A ServicesResolved: yes
[SmartTV Keyboard]# agent on
Agent registered
[SmartTV Keyboard]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 34:20:03:DF:2E:6A Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 VODAFONE REMOTE CONTROL
[SmartTV Keyboard]# pair 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47
Attempting to pair with 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 Connected: yes
[SmartTV Keyboard]# scan off
[CHG] Controller 34:20:03:DF:2E:6A Discovering: no
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 Connected: no
...
```

`busctl` [log](https://pastebin.com/ppb9s9it)
`btmon` [log](https://pastebin.com/SqRpryRF)

Fiddling with it, I got it to connect and pair.  Although I still have the repeating service resolving issue.  [Heres the log](https://pastebin.com/AafJgnZw).  It also gives me this more populated info instead

```
Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 (public)
        Name: VODAFONE REMOTE CONTROL
        Alias: VODAFONE REMOTE CONTROL
        Appearance: 0x0180
        Paired: yes
        Bonded: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        WakeAllowed: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Immediate Alert           (00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Link Loss                 (00001803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Tx Power                  (00001804-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (2141e100-213a-11e6-b67b-9e71128cae77)
        Modalias: usb:v06E7p8073d0100
        ManufacturerData Key: 0x0093
        ManufacturerData Value:
```

Whenever I try to connect, the remote stops flashing its paring light, indicating that its paired.  This happens as soon as bluetoothctl reports `Device 8C:3A:7E:52:38:47 Connected: yes`

---

**How would I go about connecting to this device?  Am I missing some module?  Is there something missing from the kernel?**

Comment: The device repeatedly disconnects and reconects (service resolving loop stuff) without any key events pushed/revieced by the host.  Ive tried within windows, and it works just fine.  Even on the same device with a windows install prior to installing linux.

Comment: I tried reading in the btmon log into Wireshark and it is not the correct format. You need to do `--write <file>`     to save the log in btsnoop format.

Comment: I ran `btmon --write btmon.log` and got this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1krxfEQ0QCxnD-N3U-KGnYA4JN_rXc1Yf/view?usp=sharing I would assume packet data would look more... Raw and large?  This is neither, doesnt seem right!  This command was let to run while the remote was attempting to connect multiple times, it is paired, but seeming to fail at `ServicesResolved`

Comment: Looking at `btmon.log` in Wireshark... before the disconnect it is receiving the following error `bluetoothd. profiles/input/hog-lib.c: report_read_cb() Error reading Report value: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error.`. Did you compile BlueZ yourself of is that the default version with Arch Linux(5.19.12)

Comment: Its all fresh off pacman.  Nothing is manually compiled

Comment: Might be one to raise with the BlueZ developers. http://www.bluez.org/contact/